# Retrieve mouse position in JavaFX without event

Tags: java, javafx, position, mouse-cursor

I want to retrieve the x and y coordinates of the current mouse position before showing a stage.

So far, the only way I found to get the mouse position in JavaFX is within a `MouseEvent`, which does not apply to my situation. Furthermore, I found the possibility to retrieve the position via `java.awt.MouseInfo`. This, however, I think is a bad idea (I use JavaFX not AWT) and, at least in my case, results in a `HeadlessException`.

Is there an other clean possibility to retrieve the mouse position in JavaFX without getting too hackish (e.g. simulating a MouseEvent just for getting the position)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not an expert, but as far as I know, this won't be easy. Mouse/cursor is generally an OS element, you are not going to get it until you have a window to capture it. You would probably need to go down to native level (JNA?), or you would need to create and show a transparent `Stage`, then grab the coordinates and then discard that transparent stage.

Comment: @Jai Thank you for your feedback. This might be indeed the case, and therefore to get a clean  solution one maybe can not but somehow simulate a `MouseEvent`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could get mouse coordinates using Robot class. Here is an example.

```
com.sun.glass.ui.Robot robot =
                com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();

        int y = robot.getMouseY();
        System.out.println("y point = " + y);
        int x = robot.getMouseX();
        System.out.println("x point= " + x);
```

It tried it on linux (elementary OS) and it works.

**Update**: 
After some googling, I found TestFX which looks like an attempt to implement a prototype for Robot class. Have a look at links given below.
https://github.com/TestFX/Robot
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2015-December/018412.html

You can also do something like this, to get the coordinates.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GlassRobot robot = new GlassRobotImpl();
        Point2D point = robot.getMouseLocation();
        double x = point.getX();
        double y = point.getY();
        System.out.println("y = " + y);
        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        if(x > 10) {
              primaryStage.show();
       }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Comment: `com.sun.glass.ui.Robot` is part of the internal API and as far as I am informed it will not be so easily accessible in Java 9 (please correct me, if I am wrong). I am trying to get clean solution for JavaFX.

Comment: After some googling, I found a link where it says that Glass Robot API will be the replacement for com.sun.glass.ui.Robot class. So, you should not worry. Have a look at the link given below. bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090763

Comment: Thank you for the  links. It really seems like that there currently is no clean solution possible.  Therefore I will mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Since 11 it has a robot called `javafx.scene.robot.Robot` which seems more appropriate to use in JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

As [@lambad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45204397/5932611) suggested Robot class seems to be a decent way to achieve your need.

I think it is more appropiate to use JavaFX version of Robot which is [`javafx.scene.robot.Robot`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html).

You could simply use `getMousePosition()` method which returns the current mouse (x,y) screen coordinates as a `javafx.geometry.Point2D`.

```
import javafx.scene.robot.Robot;

Robot robot = new Robot();

System.out.println("X is: " + robot.getMousePosition().getX());
System.out.println("Y is: " + robot.getMousePosition().getY());
```

Note: 
Robot objects must be constructed and used on the JavaFX Application Thread.